# Getting an error when trying to import pygame

Tags: python-2.7, import, pygame

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame-1.9.1release-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame-1.9.1release-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pygame/base.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SDL_EnableUNICODE
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame-1.9.1release-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pygame/base.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame-1.9.1release-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pygame/base.so
```

Hi, Im trying to run pygame with python 2.7. I have everything installed but when I import pygame I get the above error message. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?`from pygame.locals import *`